# Spring annotation for REST layer

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm developing a RESTful service using ApacheCXF. I'm using Spring to inject the bean at each layer. I've three layer - REST layer, Service layer (Business logic layer) and DAO layer. I understand that we can annotate Service layer with @Service and DAO layer with @Repository but how do we annotate Rest class ? Do you suggest to annotate it with @Controller ? I've seen many examples where Rest class is annotated as @Controller if you're developing REST using Spring MVC. IMO, Spring MVC comes into play if you have deal with presentation layer as well (I may be wrong, don't have much idea about it) but this is just a web service which is hosted on one server to consume some data by some other application. I've not used Spring MVC in my past, but when would you suggest to develop REST services using Spring MVC? What's the benefit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already using Spring, then Spring MVC is the way to write a RESTful service.

Prior to Spring 3, Spring MVC was very much focussed on traditional model-view-controller web apps that typically returned HTML to a web browser. Spring 3 added support for building RESTful services using Spring @Controllers typically configured to return JSON or XML payloads.

Rather than rehashing what's already been written, [this blog post](http://spring.io/blog/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/) is a good introduction to the REST support that was added in Spring 3 and outlines a number of the benefits.

Comment: Thanks for response. One more ques - Jersey,RestEasy & Apache-CXF are the implementation of JAX-RS. Where does Spring MVC fit here ? Is it one of the implementation of JAX-RS or does Spring MVC exist along with one of the implementation ? What benefit do we get if uses Spring MVC for developing REST ful services ?

Comment: Spring MVC doesn't implement the JAX-RS specification. By using Spring MVC for your RESTful service you'll get a programming model that's consistent with the rest of your application which is already using Spring. That should make it easier to develop and maintain.